# why does I must specify the type of only one lambda parameter in this context in Java 8?

Tags: sorting, lambda, java-8, stream

I want to "descending sort" people according to length of their name as the following

```
        List<Person> sorted = people.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getName().length()).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but the compiler complains:

```
  java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable p of type java.lang.Object
```

And I have to declare `p` explicitly:

```
        List<Person> sorted = people.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Person p) -> p.getName().length()).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My question is: why must I specify the type of parameter?

General question: generally, when must one declare only one parameter of a lambda  expression explicitly?